# Why didn't General Martok receive discommendation in Star Trek: Deep Space Nine?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

Why didn't General Martok receive discommendation, due to being captured by the Jem'Hadar and failing to commit suicide?

Answer (score 24):

Klingons are allowed (by honour) to not commit suicide if there's a reasonable chance that they'll be able to escape from their captors. Much like the 'bad apples' of [Colditz Castle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colditz_Castle), prisoners that require guarding are also tying up their enemy's resources.

> **GARAK:** *Aren't you Klingons supposed to kill yourselves when you're taken prisoner?*
>
> **WORF:** *Not when there are still enemies to fight.*
>
> **MARTOK:** *Or hope of escape. If you are Worf then you must be Garak. He said you would come.*
>
> <sub><sup>[DS9: In Purgatory's Shadow](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/512.htm)</sup></sub>

Answer (score 9):

IIRC it was in that very episode that some Starfleet member mentioned that survival is not dishonorable if you get captured and later escape *with valuable information*.

Comment: Can you provide a quote that backs this up?

Comment: I don't remember this. I'd also like a quote.

Comment: @Valorum - quote edited in before I noticed you had answered with the same! : p

Comment: @NKCampbell - My issue with this answer is that the quote from the episode ***doesn't*** say this. It says something entirely different